# Elliptic pde and boundary layer estimates

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes

I have a question that is related to finding some boundary layer estimates.  I am sure there is a general method for this but I don't know it.

I will pose the problem in two dimensions (but here there is really no problem since one doesn't need this approach).  Let's assume we have a bunch of smooth solutions of
$$-\Delta u^m(x,y) + u^m  = (u^m)^p $$ in $B_1^+$  (the upper half ball) and we suppose that $u^m_y(x,y) \le 0$ in the domain or at least near the bottom boundary.   Lets assume that $ t_m = u^m(0,0) = \max u^m \rightarrow \infty$ (so here since the dimension is $N=2$ we can directly rule this out… but let's assume we can't… or pose this same problem in higher dimensions).    I want to rescale the problem but I only want to rescale in $y$ (if I rescale both I get a Laplacian and then i am capable of doing stuff).   So consider $$v^m(x,y)= \frac{u^m(x, \epsilon_m y)}{t_m}.$$  Then $v^m$ solves
$$-v^m_{yy} - \epsilon_m^2 v^m_{xx} + \epsilon_m^2 v^m = (\epsilon_m^2 t_m^{p-1}) (v^m)^p$$ for some domain.

So we take $\epsilon_m$ such that the term in the brackets on the right is one.   Now if we could show that $ \epsilon_m^2 v^m_{xx} \rightarrow 0$ then we should have our limiting equation just depending on $y$  (or at least its an ode in y with a parameter $x$).   So we'd roughly get $ -v_{yy}(y)= v^p$ for $ y>0$  with $ v(0)=1$ and $ v \le 1$ and then we can proceed to get a contradiction.

**So my question is**:  how does one normally get enough estimates on this $u_{xx}^m $ term to show we can take it going to zero?

In some sense this convergence could be quite weak.  For instance let's assume that we knew $ v^m \rightarrow v$ uniformly and hence this is sufficient that we have $ v(0,0)=1$   then we can test the pde on some test functions and put all the derivatives of $v^m_{xx}$ on the test function and that would allow me to do what I want.

I do see I can get $H^1$ estimates on $v^m$ with epsilon terms;  but I am not sure this will be sufficient to get the uniform convergence I want.